# Puppeteer: How to pass an object to page.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to pass my custom object to `page.evaluate()`, but when I run the script it throws a following error:

`Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'p1' of undefined`.

How can I use a custom object in browser context?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function obj() {
    this.p1 = 'a';
    this.p2 = {
        p21: 'b'
    };
};

(async function () {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/');

        page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

        const obj1 = new obj();

        await page.evaluate((obj1) => {
            console.log(obj1.p1);
            console.log(obj1.p2.p21);
            console.log(obj1.p2.p21);
        });

        browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass an object like following,

```
await page.evaluate((obj) => { // <-- use it as parameter of this function
            console.log(obj.p1); // <-- use it inside as you wish 
            console.log(obj.p2.p21);
            console.log(obj.p2.p21);
}, obj); //<-- pass it here as argument
```

Remember the object you pass will be serialized, so circular object or function etc will not work.